# Power BI not finding relationships when loading SQLite db

Tags: sqlite, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When I attempt to load a database into Power BI it does not detect the relationships between tables despite having foreign keys defined.

This is a cut down version of my table definitions which I've tested:

"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MetaCore (
MetaID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
SimID INTEGER,
Name TEXT,
Description TEXT,
PG TEXT
);"

"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RtnABC (
MetaID INTEGER,
ID TEXT,
A REAL,
B REAL,
C integer NOT NULL,
Date text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (MetaID, ID, C, Date),
FOREIGN KEY (MetaID) REFERENCES MetaCore (MetaID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES FundsMeta (ISIN)
);"

Power BI recognises MetaID in the MetaCore table as decimal instead of integer which could be a clue to the issue. If I cchnage this datatype in the BI data model I can then get it to autodetect the relationship successfully (after loading).

Many thanks all!

I have tried changing the DSN settings to check the foreign key checkbox. I have used the latest SQLite3 ODBC driver.
I have tried using the Power BI standard SQLite3 ODBC DSC settings as well as adding a new one through ODBC Data Sources.  I'm not an expert in this area so there might be somthing I'm missing.
I have followed some instructions on youtube videos and I'm not doing anything different regarding the ODBC setup and BI load procedure.
The data load settings in Power BI include "import relationships from data sources on first load".

Comment: The issue lies with Power BI not recognising the data type of the key fiedls correctly.  In some tables the field MetaID is being assigned a decimal type where as other tables it is assigned the integer type (which is correct).  I cant see why this is happening.